ESP32 getting brownout!

I have designed a fan controller circuit using esp32. The circuit was working when I connected with a bulb. When I connected with a fan the chip is getting turned on and immediately it turns off. This issue occurs only initially then it will work perfectly. The chip is showing similar characteristics also at turning off time. Also after testing so many times the board got short circuited. I checked with two boards both times appeared like this. Can anyone shower some idea on this?

Your schematic has zero information on ESP power supply. It is impossible to discuss brownout issues without it.

Need to see layout are you using proper clearance?

At what point does the ESP32, the 12V rail and the fan supply join up? Do the 3 power supplies share a significant length of cable? Does the fan starting up cause the ESP32 supply to dip? Can you check this? Have you tried running a separate supply for the fan back to the distribution board or similar?

The esp32 is getting reset when the fan is turned on. We haven't tried to give a  seperate supply because if we are giving a different power supply, we wouldn't be able to control the speed of the fan. We checked the circuit by giving bulb on the output but at that time there was no issues.

@AakasPulikkal OK humour us, try powering the ESP32 from a separate supply, such as batteries, just for a test.  It sounds very much as if some sort of power surge (which you don't get with a bulb) is tripping the ESP23 when the fan motor starts
